# Cannot authenticate anymore after adding a line to common-auth

Tags: password, pam, passwd

I have followed online advice to set a script that would run after a failed password attemp. I added the line in `/etc/pam.d/common-auth`

```
auth    [default=ignore]                pam_exec.so seteuid /root/script
```

after the line

```
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so nullok_secure
```

I am now unable to log in with any user:

```
$ su root
Password: 
su: Authentication failure
```

**Why cannot I connect anymore with this the new entered line?**

Full file (`/etc/pam.d/common-auth`):

```
#
# /etc/pam.d/common-auth - authentication settings common to all services
#
# This file is included from other service-specific PAM config files,
# and should contain a list of the authentication modules that define
# the central authentication scheme for use on the system
# (e.g., /etc/shadow, LDAP, Kerberos, etc.).  The default is to use the
# traditional Unix authentication mechanisms.
#
# As of pam 1.0.1-6, this file is managed by pam-auth-update by default.
# To take advantage of this, it is recommended that you configure any
# local modules either before or after the default block, and use
# pam-auth-update to manage selection of other modules.  See
# pam-auth-update(8) for details.

# here are the per-package modules (the "Primary" block)
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so nullok_secure
auth    [default=ignore]                pam_exec.so seteuid /root/script
# here's the fallback if no module succeeds
auth    requisite           pam_deny.so
# prime the stack with a positive return value if there isn't one already;
# this avoids us returning an error just because nothing sets a success code
# since the modules above will each just jump around
auth    required            pam_permit.so
# and here are more per-package modules (the "Additional" block)
```

Answer (score 1):

`success=1` means that, on success, PAM should skip the next module and go to the one after ... which is `pam_deny.so`. By inserting a module between `pam_unix` and `pam_deny`, the skip count changed. Use `success=2` for `pam_unix.so` if you want to add a module to be run on failure after it.